# Is it possible to use rsync to sync all files of a given type recursively?

Tags: recursion, rsync

Every iOS device we have automatically uploads photos and videos to its own folder inside an SMB share on our Ubuntu box.

On my mac, this would be `/Volumes/Ironman/familyMedia/<iosdevice>`

So each device has a folder under `/familyMedia`

If I wanted to move all of the video files from each device's sub-folder into a single folder: `/familyMedia/videos` while preserving all of the meta data and date information for the file (`rsync -azvp`), could I do this with rsync.

Basically rsync would find all *.mov files in the familyMedia folder structure, recursively, and move them to one folder.

Possible?